# Re-ordering a Bootstrap 4 grid

Tags: bootstrap-4

I want a layout such that:

```
Mobile (< col-md)

"Call to Actions" displays as one row 100% wide
"Categories" displays as one row 100% wide
"Button ads " displays as one row 100% wide

PC (> col-md)

"Call to Actions" & "Button ads"  displays as one row 100% wide between them and 1 to 2  width ratio
"Categories" displays as one row 100% wide
```

I seem to have managed this, see grabs below:

[image]

**Code:**

```
<div class="row">

  <div style='background-color: #ccc;' class="col-md-4 order-md-1">
   Call to Actions
  </div>

  <div style='background-color: #eee;' class="col-md-12 order-md-12">
   Categories
  </div> 

  <div style='background-color: #ddd;' class="col-md-8 order-md-2">
     Button ads       
  </div> 

</div>
```

**Questions**

A) I have three columns in one row adding up to 24 - it wraps as I would like - is this OK? BTW the container this grid is in has a max width of 1100.

B) Most of the examples I see for ordering go from order-xx-1  to order-xx-12 - for 3 columns could I just used 1,2,3? Seems to work OK.

Comment: Did you try col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 for mobile(xs->extra small) it will take entire row
For tablet(sm->small) it will take 50% of the width and for md(laptop or large screen) it will take 30% of the screen..

Comment: No I just tried the code above it seems to do what I want, just checking it's valid. I don't want "call to Actions" to be 50% on desktop, 33% is fine

Comment: @aloket There's no `col-xs` in Bootstrap 4.

Comment: Thanks, @Klooven for updating me... :D

Comment: @aloket  As reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#grid-options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A**

Yes, It is correct. [Extra columns wraps onto a new line](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#column-wrapping).

**B**

> You can set the order by breakpoint (e.g., .order-1.order-md-2). Includes support for 1 through 12 across all five grid tiers. - [bootstrap-4](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#reordering)

You have used the `order-*` classes properly. However, since you do not change the order of the `first` column, you should not use an `oder-*`class for it. Use `order-md-1` for `Button ads` and `order-md-last` for `Catigories` column.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div style='background-color: #ccc;' class="col-md-4">
    Call to Actions
  </div>
  <div style='background-color: #eee;' class="col-md-12 order-md-last">
    Categories
  </div>
  <div style='background-color: #ddd;' class="col-md-8 order-md-1">
    Button ads
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rKMEbY

Another solution is to reorder the columns for mobiles.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div style='background-color: #ccc;' class="col-12 col-md-4 ">
    Call to Actions
  </div>

  <div style='background-color: #ddd;' class="col-12 order-12 order-md-0 col-md-8 ">
    Button ads
  </div>
  <div style='background-color: #eee;' class="col-12 order-2 order-md-0 col-md-12 ">
    Categories
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OEReYP

## Update

You do not have to use `order-12` for the last column. It is totally fine to use `order-md-3` for the last column, if you have 3 columns. Or if you have four columns, `order-md-4` for the forth one. If you have less than 13 columns, `order-12`  and `order-last` has the same `function`. It is just a secure way to use `order-12` or `order-last` for the last column. For readability, use `order-md-0` or `order-first` for the first `column`.

The `order-*` classes uses `css-order`. Read about it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items).

Comment: Thanks for that. Re question B I was asking do I need to end on order 12 when I have just 3 columns. And is there any harm in assigning an order to the first column even if not needed, for readability ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's perfectly valid Bootstrap because...

> "If more than 12 columns are placed within a single row, each group of
>   extra columns will, as one unit, wrap onto a new line."

http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#column-wrapping

And the `order-*` classes only have to be used as needed, 12 is the max. You'd only use all 12 if you had 12 individual column units in 1 row.

To optimize use of `order-*` you only need to reverse the 2nd and 3rd columns on `md`. The 1st call remains in its natural order so it doesn't need a specific `order-*` class. You can use any two `order-md-*` classes along as "Button ads" is less than "Categories".

```
<div class="row">
      <div style='background-color: #ccc;' class="col-md-4">
       Call to Actions
      </div>
      <div style='background-color: #eee;' class="col-md-12 order-md-2">
       Categories
      </div> 
      <div style='background-color: #ddd;' class="col-md-8 order-md-1">
      Button ads       
      </div> 
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/DZfhbAyEUL

Comment: Thanks, two very good answerers, I accepted the other one as that was first.